# How can I make my bot say something when it or another bot is used in the command? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot "check" to see if the person mentioned in my command is a bot, but I'm not really sure how. Here is my code:

```
@client.command(aliases=['Noob', 'NOOB'])
async def noob(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    member = member.mention
    text = [ f'{member} is a certified Noob:tm:',
               f'{member} is a noob!!',
               ctx.author.mention + f' calls {member} a noob, but they use a Uno reverse card',
               ctx.author.mention + f' attemts to call {member} a noob, but fails.',
               f'{member} is the biggest noob there is!!!',
               f'{member} is a noob, but a really cool one tbh :eyes:',
               ctx.author.mention + f' *thinks* {member} is a noob']

    if [this is where I'm trying to add the check] == True:
        await ctx.send('sorry, i will not betray my kind :pensive:')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(text)}')
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`member.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.bot) to check if the member is bot or not.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['Noob', 'NOOB'])
async def noob(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    mention= member.mention
    text = [ f'{mention} is a certified Noob:tm:',
               f'{mention} is a noob!!',
               ctx.author.mention + f' calls {mention} a noob, but they use a Uno reverse card',
               ctx.author.mention + f' attemts to call {mention} a noob, but fails.',
               f'{mention} is the biggest noob there is!!!',
               f'{mention} is a noob, but a really cool one tbh :eyes:',
               ctx.author.mention + f' *thinks* {mention} is a noob']

    if member.bot:
        await ctx.send('sorry, I will not betray my kind :pensive:')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(text)}')
```